# Error is thrown but error response object is empty in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, response

I am trying to send a request to my API.

My code is like this

```
app.post('/api/create', (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.headers || !req.headers.authorization) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      status: 'error',
      err: 'No authorization header'
    });
  }

  const bits = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');
  const scheme = bits[0];
  const token = bits[1];

  jwt.verify(token, 'secret', function(err, decoded) {
    if (!!err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        status: 'error',
        err: 'Invalid credentials.'
      });
    }

    //
    const userId = decoded.id;

    //
    if (!userId) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        status: 'error',
        err: 'User id missing',
      });
    }

    //
    const { postId } = req.params;

    //
    User.findById(userId).then(user => {
      //
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          status: 'error',
          err: 'User not found',
        });
      }

      //
      Post.findById(postId).then(event => {
        //
        if (!post) {
          return res.status(400).json({
            status: 'error',
            err: 'Post not found',
          });
        }

        // ...

      }).catch(err => {
        // Could not find post
        return res.status(400).json({
          status: 'error',
          msg: 'Could not find post',
          err
        });
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      // Could not find user
      return res.status(400).json({
        status: 'error',
        msg: 'Could not find user',
        err
      });
    });
  });
});
```

but I receive an error with object

```
{
  status: 'error',
  msg: 'Could not find post',
  err: ''
}
```

i.e. the `err` is completely empty. I have no idea how to debug this. I am catching the error with `}).catch(err => {`, so I would expect it to write out the error if I ever reach the `catch()` block.

What can cause this problem?

Comment: Too much commented out here to see what is really happening. You are basically doing the wrong thing though, since any "chain" of promises should be returning and continuing and essentially having **just one catch** which is reached when any error occurs in the "chain". So for example your `User.findById()` has an "inner" call to `Post.findById()`, but this should in fact be `return Post.findById()` and the `.then()` ( and `.catch()` ) is issued on the "outer" call, and not the "inner" as you are doing.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware. Do you have an example? Should I then use `throw new Error('msg')` instead of `return res.status(400).json({ status: 'error', err: 'msg' })`?

Comment: `throw` does nothing "inside" a promise. That sort of handling, along with `try/catch` cannot be done inside promises all callbacks. It is in fact the reason that `async/await` is the preferred "sugar" here, since those constructs actually have meaning again when used in conjuntion. But like I said, your problem is in the code you are "hiding", but the general structure of what you are doing is incorrect. And that leads to such errors being difficult to trace down.